# Why does declaring returns type bytes memory give a compiler error?

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, string, bytes

If we have the following code:

```
pragma solidity >= 0.5;
contract stringsContract {
    function takesTwo(string memory str, uint idx) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes memory bytesStr = bytes(str);
        return bytesStr[idx];
    }
}
```

Why do we get `TypeError return argument bytes1 is not explicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable bytes memory)`.

The fix was to change `bytes memory` to `bytes`:

```
contract stringsContract {
        function takesTwo(string memory str, uint idx) public pure returns (byte) {
            bytes memory bytesStr = bytes(str);
            return bytesStr[idx];
        }
    }
```

Nevertheless, I'm still curious about the reason of the compilation error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not returning a `bytes memory`, so remove `[idx]`.

```
return bytesStr[idx];
```

Compiles:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract stringsContract {

    function takesTwo(string memory str, uint idx) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes memory bytesStr = bytes(str);
        return bytesStr;
    }
}
```

That doesn't use `idx` at all. If your goal is to return one of the bytes, then the function would promise a `byte`.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract stringsContract {

    function takesTwo(string memory str, uint idx) public pure returns (byte) {
        bytes memory bytesStr = bytes(str);
        return bytesStr[idx];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps;

Comment: This certainly helped me reason through the error, thank you. I had a typo in the second part of my question and left the extra `s` in bytes; should've been `byte` like you mentioned. It compiled successfully.